# Все подстроки строки

Tags: c, строки, алгоритм

Помогите написать функцию

```
char ** allSubstrings(char *string)
```

которая возвращает массив всех подстрок строки в таком порядке:

```
string

strin

tring

stri

trin

ring

str

tri

rin

ing

st

tr

ri

in

ng

s

t

r

i

n

g
```

Comment: @Dezza  Simpson, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @Fike: Это подзадача, которую я решаю в рамках большой задачи, я могу показать код, но вы едва ли что-то поймете там.

Comment: @Dezza  Simpson а весь и не нужен, нужны конкретные наработки по данной задаче и место, в котором вы остановились.

Comment: Начинаете с длины l исходной строки, выделяете все подстроки (начиная с 0, 1, ...) пока существуют, затем уменьшаете l, и так до l==1. Количество подстрок (для выделения массива указателей) -- сумма арифметической прогрессии от 1 до l. Вроде всё. Дальше только код.

Comment: И да поможет вам p+i и strncpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for (int l = strlen(string); l > 0; --l)
      for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(string) - l; ++i)
        printf("%.*s\n", l, &string[i]); // <- insert (&string[i], l) into array here
```

С аллокацией и заполнением массива, думаю, сами справитесь.